# Delete a node in a singly linked list: C

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to write a program that deletes a node from a singly linked list.

```
void Delete(char * sym) {
// Pointer variable declarations.
    struct SymbTab *search = Search(sym);
    if (search == NULL) {
        return;
    }
    struct SymbTab *p = search;
    struct SymbTab *q = p->next;
    p->symbol = p->next->symbol;
    p->addr = p->next->addr;
    p->next = p->next->next;
    size--;
    }
```

The "Search(sym)" redirects to my Search function, which returns a struct SymbTab* if it finds a match and NULL if no match is found. I keep getting a seg fault, but I'm unsure as to where I'm incorrectly assigning/declaring/etc things to memory. (edit: fixed the code indentation)

Comment: Your approach does not work when the symbol you're trying to delete is the last one in the list.  Then expressions such as `p->next->symbol` attempt to traverse the null pointer `p->next`.  Also, if your nodes are dynamically allocated, then your approach probably leaks memory.

Comment: The common solution is to find the *previous* node in the list, the one that have `next` point to `search`. Then change its `next` to be `search->next`.

Comment: I recommend you take some time with a pencil and some paper to solve problems like this. Draw a list of boxes, linked by arrows (there are the nodes and the "next" link between them). By erasing and redrawing the arrows, figure out how to solve it. Try with a few different lists (empty, one node, node in the head, node in the tail, node in the middle, etc.).

Comment: It would be worth your while to learn how to use a debugger.  If you're using an IDE then it probably has an integrated one.  If you're not using an IDE then there are standalone options available, such as `gdb`.  That would make it easy to capture the context of segfaults such as you saw, and to examine the objects involved to determine what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In a single linked list, unlike in a double linked list (where you have the reference to the previous item), you need to keep the previous item at hand, which could be done like this:

```
for (
    item_type *item = lst->head, //start with first item in the list
    *prev = NULL;                //the previous item, initially NULL
    item;                        //as long as item is not NULL
    item = item->next            //increase to next item in the list
){
    if (equals(item, item_to_delete)) { //if the item is the item you're looking for
        if (prev) { //item is not first item
            prev->next = item->next; //remove the item
        } else { //first item in the list
            lst->head = item->next; //set new head
        }
        delete(item); //delete the removed item
        break; //or return
    }
    prev = item; //keep the previous item at hand
}
```